# making VueJS expressions debug-able

Tags: debugging, vue.js

My vue js data has some arrays, and in the template I am trying to render them using `v-for` loops.

something like:

```
<tr v-for="d in [0,1,2,3]"><td>{{data.people[d].name}}</td></tr>
<tr v-for="d in [0,1,2,3]"><td>{{data.places[d].name}}</td></tr>
<tr v-for="d in [0,1,2,3]"><td>{{data.orders[d].id}}</td></tr>
<tr v-for="d in [0,1,2,3]"><td>{{data.other_array[d].id}}</td></tr>
<tr v-for="d in [0,1,2,3]"><td>{{data.more_array[d].som_property}}</td></tr>
```

and I am getting an error that looks like this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at eval (eval at createFunction (vue.js:10518), <anonymous>:2:3084)
    at Proxy.renderList (vue.js:3666)
    at Proxy.eval (eval at createFunction (vue.js:10518), <anonymous>:2:2915)
    at Vue$3.Vue._render (vue.js:4465)
    at Vue$3.updateComponent (vue.js:2765)
    at Watcher.get (vue.js:3113)
    at new Watcher (vue.js:3102)
    at mountComponent (vue.js:2772)
    at Vue$3.$mount (vue.js:8416)
    at Vue$3.$mount (vue.js:10777)
logError @ vue.js:1719
globalHandleError @ vue.js:1710
handleError @ vue.js:1699
Vue._render @ vue.js:4467
updateComponent @ vue.js:2765
get @ vue.js:3113
Watcher @ vue.js:3102
mountComponent @ vue.js:2772
Vue$3.$mount @ vue.js:8416
Vue$3.$mount @ vue.js:10777
Vue._init @ vue.js:4557
Vue$3 @ vue.js:4646
(anonymous) @ astromap.html:291
```

I do understand that it means that somewhere one of my arrays is not initialized, and I will find that array, I also know I can write using guards and use v-if .

What bothers me is that The above stack trace seems quite useless.

my Q is:

Is there a better way to write such templates, not to prevent them from failing, but so that when they do fail I will get a more indicative output?

Alternatively, Is there any other debugging magic (e.g. some `lastParsedExpression` secret variable) that I can use in the debug console that can tell me what was the expression that failed?

**UPDATE**: edited to emphasis that there are multiple places where the error could happen.

Comment: What's makes the stack trace useless when literally the first line tells you what's wrong?

Comment: consider a template that has 10 such arrays with different names...
people[d].name  places[d].name  .... and so on
how does the stack trace help me know which of those arrays is the culprit ?

Comment: If chrome is your browser of choice, are you using the vue.js dev tools extension? Between the component tree and it's time travel feature I don't offer encounter something I can't track down.

Comment: So this tool reportedly has the ability to subscribe to specific state variables. Never used it myself but looks like it could be useful. http://vuetron.io

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [ErrorBoundary](https://gist.github.com/yyx990803/9bdff05e5468a60ced06c29c39114c6b#error-handling-with-errorcaptured-hook).

```
Vue.component('ErrorBoundary', {
  data: () => ({ error: null }),
  errorCaptured (err, vm, info) {
    this.error = `${err.stack}\n\nfound in ${info} of component`
    return false
  },
  render (h) {
    if (this.error) {
      return h('pre', { style: { color: 'red' }}, this.error)
    }
    // ignoring edge cases for the sake of demonstration
    return this.$slots.default[0]
  }
})

<error-boundary>
  <another-component/>
</error-boundary>
```

Comment: this sounds like what I was looking for but I was not able to actually use it yet. I am also not sure if and how to apply this relates to a page that uses no vue components other then a single app.

Answer (score 0):

The first item in your v-for array is `0`. The error states:

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

You're attempting to access property `0` on `people`

```
people[d].name
```

Where do you have `people` defined?

The error is telling you an object is not defined, not an array.

Comment: as I said, I know that... that was not my Q.

Comment: Actually you didn't say that. `one of my arrays is not initialized`. The stack trace is pretty clear what the problem is.

Comment: You are right, undefined and not initialized is not 100% the same. The real code looks more like some_data_container.people[d].name so actually `people` is not "defined" anywhere - it was just an object propery that was supposed to be assigned an array. and since it was not initialized with an actual array then `some_data_container.people` was undefined and I was not able to access its [0] ...
that said, my Q was not what was the error... but rather how can I tell which of the expressions that is being rendered/parsed is the one that failes. (consider multimple `container.attr[idx]` 's ).